# SQL Server Trigger error for compiling

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I want to modify an existing trigger but I get an error.
After modifying this AFTER DELETE trigger when I delete a record from that table I get

> The definition of object 'del_nota' has changed since it was compiled.

I've tried all the following

- restart SQL Server
- EXEC sp_recompile 'dbo.del_nota'
- ALTER TABLE note DISABLE/ENABLE TRIGGER del_nota

But I get the same error
On that table I also have 2 triggers for Insert and for Update.
I've disabled them but still the same error.
That trigger initially deletes some records from another table.
I've added after that an insert statement in other table with a select the deleted record from the Deleted table.
What should I do ?
Thank you !

Comment: Add code sample - your explanation is a bit unclear.

Comment: Are you able to SCRIPT AS CREATE trigger (from SQL Studio) - then drop trigger and recreate (with modification) from a generated script? Of course it's not instant operation (you should prevent users from using that db, table for a while if a trigger is important).

Comment: Deleted it and then recreate. Same error